# Solução C# MVC não executa JavaScript no IIS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Tenho uma solução em C# onde utilizo MVC. Nela tenho uma View para inclusão de itens de produtos. Nesta view tenho uma DropList como especificada abaixo:

Drop List

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProdutoId, "Produto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ProdutoId", null, String.Empty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "PesquisaProduto(value)" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProdutoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Utilizo um JavaScript para acessar uma Action no Controller afim de, ao selecionar um produto, um texto com o valor de venda do produto selecionado seja preenchido. Abaixo o script:

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PesquisaProduto(codigoProdutoId) {
        var url = "/ItemPedidoes/DadosProdutos/" + codigoProdutoId;
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {
            $("#ValorUnitario").val(data);
        })
    }
```

Controller:

```
public decimal DadosProdutos(int? id)
{
    decimal _return = 0;
    if (id == null) {
        _return = 0;
    } else
    {
        var produtoSelecao = db.Produtos.Find(id);

        if (produtoSelecao.PrecoVenda == null || produtoSelecao.PrecoVenda == 0)
        {
            _return = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            _return = (decimal)produtoSelecao.PrecoVenda;
        }

    }
    return _return;
}
```

Ocorre que, nos testes, rodando no Visual Studio, tudo funciona perfeitamente, só que ao instalar no IIS o script não funciona. Ele não preenche o valor, como se o script estivesse com erro..

Alguém saberia dizer se há alguma configuração no IIS que deve ser alterada?

Minha versão do IIS é a 10.0.14393.0 e rodo numa máquina windows 10.

Comment: Jovem, veja se o console não mostra algum erro. Verifique também a aba 'network' do seu navegador.

Comment: Prezado.. Consegui resolver.. Na verdade precisei alterar a forma que estava montando a URL.. Vi no Log o IIS que o GET estava retornando 404!!..

Comment: já tive varios problemas chamando o controller na chamada ajax assim `../controller/exemplo`, quando mando para o servidor não funciona, depois de muito bater a cabeça descobri que sempre funciona assim no seu caso ao invés de `var url = "/ItemPedidoes/DadosProdutos/"`, use `var url = "@Url.Action("DadosProdutos", "ItemPedidoes")"`

Comment: Fala Vinícius.. estou utilizando "../../Controller/Action/codigo".. Deu certinho tanto no IIS quanto no VisualStudio.. Vlw!!

Answer (score 2):

Com base na dica do amigo [@Linq](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18246/linq) , verifiquei o log do IIS e descobri a seguinte linha lá:

```
2017-10-11 17:13:16 ::1 GET /Loja4/ItemPedidoes/Create/~/ItemPedidoes/DadosProdutos/1 - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+rv:56.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/56.0 http://localhost/Loja4/ItemPedidoes/Create/3 404 0 2 5
```

Ou seja, a URL retornava 404 no servidor e para que a URL fosse passada de forma correta no GET precisei alterar a "montagem" da mesma..

Abaixo como ficou o script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PesquisaProduto(codigoProdutoId) {
        var url = "/../../ItemPedidoes/DadosProdutos/" + codigoProdutoId;
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {
            $("#ValorUnitario").val(data);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Seria melhor usar uma função pra retornar o caminho correto. Com essa modificação não vai mais funcionar da maneira antiga...

Comment: O que você chama de funcionar da maneira antiga @LINQ? Na verdade está funcionando tanto no IIS quanto no VisualStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Altere a chamada script para:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PesquisaProduto(codigoProdutoId) {
        var url = "@Url.Action("DadosProdutos")/" + codigoProdutoId;
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {
            $("#ValorUnitario").val(data);
        })
    }
```